# How to prevent Undefined property: stdClass::$data when hitting an API

Tags: php, laravel, api

I have created a form using Laravel whereby I am fetching data from the user which is supposed to be stored in an API. I have writen a separate function called **global_curl** that is supposed to post data to the API.The problem is when I try to hit the REST API via post request I get the following error: **(1/1) ErrorException
Undefined property: stdClass::$data**

**My controller**

```
//Post Request of plan entries
public function validatePlanEntries(Request $request){
    $data = array(
        'DobPrincipalTraveller' => $request->dob,
        'TravelStartDate' => $request->departure_date,
        'TravelEndDate' => $request->return_date,
        'CoverOption' => $request->cover,
        'DobOfSpouse' => $request->spousedob,
        'Children' => '2018-10-07',
        'WithSpouse' => 0
    );
    // dd($data);
   /*Posts data to Travel Plans API*/
   $travelplan_data = $this->global_Curl($data, 'api/travel/get-plans')->data;
}
```

**Curl Function**

```
public function global_Curl($data, $url){
    //dd($_ENV['API_ENDPOINT_NGINX_IP'] . '/' . $url);
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, ($_ENV['API_ENDPOINT_NGINX_IP'] . '/' . $url));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
    curl_close($ch);
    return $response;
}
```

**API data structure from POSTMAN**

```
{
    "DobPrincipalTraveller":"1978-01-22",
    "TravelStartDate":"2018-10-20",
    "TravelEndDate":"2018-10-25",
    "CoverOption":"Standard",
    "WithSpouse":"1",
    "DobOfSpouse":"1985-03-18",
    "Children":[
        {
            "DateOfBirth":"2015-05-23"
        },
        {
            "DateOfBirth":"2016-09-13"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: $travelplan_data = $this->global_Curl($data, 'api/travel/get-plans')->data; it should be $travelplan_data = $this->global_Curl($data, 'api/travel/get-plans');

Comment: @SalmanZafar   Tried it,, the error still persists.

Comment: public function global_Curl(array $data, $url){} try this

Comment: @SalmanZafar Tried it,, still throws the error

Answer (score 1):

It should be like this.

```
$travelplan_data = $this->global_Curl($data, 'api/travel/get-plans');
```

Answer (score 1):

it should be like this:
as you are passing array to function so it should be able to accept array as parameter so you should define you curl function like i did.

```
//Post Request of plan entries
public function validatePlanEntries(Request $request){
    $data = array(
        'DobPrincipalTraveller' => $request->dob,
        'TravelStartDate' => $request->departure_date,
        'TravelEndDate' => $request->return_date,
        'CoverOption' => $request->cover,
        'DobOfSpouse' => $request->spousedob,
        'Children' => '2018-10-07',
        'WithSpouse' => 0
    );
    // dd($data);
   /*Posts data to Travel Plans API*/
   $travelplan_data = $this->global_Curl($data, 'api/travel/get-plans');
}

public function global_Curl(array $data, $url){
    //dd($_ENV['API_ENDPOINT_NGINX_IP'] . '/' . $url);
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, ($_ENV['API_ENDPOINT_NGINX_IP'] . '/' . $url));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
    curl_close($ch);
    return $response;
}
```

try this..
hope it will work

Comment: (1/1) ErrorException   Undefined property: stdClass::$data

Comment: The variable called data inside the controller is the point of error

Comment: if you dd($data) is it getting printed?

Comment: Yes,, all the data is being printed

Comment: @Pweb now dd in curl function and see if all the data is bng passed or not.. dd($data) in curl function..